# SqlDataAdapter.Fill method is throws SqlException when the BUILTIN/Administrators language is British English

Tags: sqlexception, sqldataadapter

our c# application uses SqlDataAdapter to fetch data from the DB to present in a report. For some reason the SqlDataAdapter.Fill method is throwing below SqlException when the BUILTIN/Administrators language is British English. When it is English, it is working fine. I debugged my C# code but didn't get a clue why this is happening. Can some one help me overcome this exception?

```
{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at ReportViewer.ReportViewer.CreateReportDataSource(ReportRequest reportRequest, String selectString, ReportParameterInfoCollection parameters, DataSet dataSet, SqlConnection connection) in C:\ISSCode\branches\Samra2Freeze\Controls\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.cs:line 367
ClientConnectionId:fc8c8835-3d91-423e-b467-64c6adf6fecc
Error Number:8114,State:5,Class:16}
```

Comment: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime. Check your data before binding it to the report.

Comment: I am not binding manually but populating it from an .rdlc file(Report builder 2.0). Actually it works fine when the language is English. Issue is with British English. And in one of our production systems it is reverse. I tried changing CultureInfo to en-UK/en-US/CultureInvariant in the threads where the Select string(read from rdlc file) is processed but no luck. Any quick help is really appreciated.

Comment: I think you should be fixed the format date data for this field in the query. So you don't need to set CultureInfo.